# Querying "like" in pymongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I have researched this but can not find why what I am trying is not working, and will warn that I am somewhat new to python and very new to mongodb. I have a mongo database of tweets in JSON which I am trying to query through Python and pymongo. I want returned the 'text' and 'created_at' fields for all tweets that contain "IP".

I have tried the following, which works perfectly when I do this through the terminal:

```
db.tweets.find({text:/IP/},{text:1,created_at:1})
```

In Python, after experimenting I have found that I need to put the field names between quotes. I have gotten the following similar query to work:

```
cursor = db.tweets.find({'created_at':"Thu Apr 28 09:55:57 +0000 2016"},{'text':1,'created_at':1})
```

But when I try:

```
db.tweets.find({"text": /.*IP.*/},{'text':1,'created_at':1})
```

or

```
cursor = db.tweets.find({'text':/IP/},{'text':1,'created_at':1})
```

I get a

```
'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' at the "/IP/" part of the code.
```

I am using mongo 3.4.6 and python 3.5.2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Python does not have special syntax for regexes like JavaScript has.

## Using `re`

You need to **compile the regex** with the [**`re` module**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re):

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('.*IP.*', re.IGNORECASE)  # compile the regex

cursor = db.tweets.find({'text':rgx},{'text':1,'created_at':1})
```

You can use `re.IGNORECASE` as flag if you want to match `iP`, `Ip` and `ip` as well. If you do not want that, you can drop the `re.IGNORECASE` part.

## Using `'$regex'` notation

Or you can specify that you are working with a regex with:

```
cursor = db.tweets.find({'text':{'$regex':'IP'}},{'text':1,'created_at':1})
```